# Session if else statement

Tags: php, html, session, isset

I am trying to display the information A if login as user and information B if login as admin. The problem here is that, I am only able to execute the first `if statement` and the `else statement` which means I am able to login. However, it will never get into the `else if statement`. Can anyone help me, I am not sure what is the problem here.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbdatabase = "test";
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbdatabase, $db);
?>
```

## somewhere.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
include("configuration.php");
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_EXIST']) == true && isset($_SESSION['SESS_TYPE']) == 'A' ){ ?>
            //this is the user html information form
        <?php } 
    else if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_EXIST']) == true && isset($_SESSION['SESS_TYPE1']) == 'B' ){ ?>
            //this is the admin html information form
    <?php } else { ?>
            //ask user/admin to login html form
            <form action ="login.php">
               <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

## login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require("configuration.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_EXIST']) == TRUE) {
header("Location: somewhere.php");
die();
}
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$pass =  $_POST['Pass'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email='$email' and Pass ='$pass' " ;
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Email='$email' and Pass ='$pass' " ;
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$rows1 = mysql_num_rows($res1);

if($rows == 1)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'] = $row['Email'];
$_SESSION['SESS_NAME'] = $row['Name'];
$_SESSION['SESS_PASS'] = $row['Pass'];
$_SESSION['SESS_TYPE'] = 'A';
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED'] = 1;
header("Location: somewhere.php");
die();

}
else if($rows1 == 1)
{
$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1);
$_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL1'] = $row['Email'];
$_SESSION['SESS_NAME1'] = $row['Name'];
$_SESSION['SESS_PASS1'] = $row['Pass'];
$_SESSION['SESS_TYPE1'] = 'B';
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED'] = 1;
header("Location: somewhere.php");
die();
}
else {
echo '<script language = "javascript">';
echo 'alert("Fail login")';
echo '</script>';
echo "<script>window.location.assign('somewhere.php')</script>";
die();
}
?>
```

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['SESS_TYPE'])` returns __true__ (and sometimes false). And `'A'` is always __true__

Comment: Use Prepared Statements in order to prevent SQL-Injections

Comment: may I know why 'A' will always return true given that I have set 'B' is also true?

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: you have an extra `?>` (php closing tag) at the end of the `somewhere.php` script

Comment: that was a typo. Shouldn't be there

Comment: Also you should check if the session is started using `if ( session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();`

Comment: Your DB structure is a mess. Use a separate table for account types and `join` it. Passwords should be hashed. User input **NEVER** goes in SQL queries. and the probable root of your issues... this is an incorrect comparison `isset($_SESSION['SESS_TYPE']) == 'A'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't reset your SESSION when you Logout. Try this:
**Login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require("configuration.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_EXIST']) == TRUE) {
header("Location: somewhere.php");
die();
}
session_unset();
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$pass =  $_POST['Pass'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email='$email' and Pass ='$pass' " ;
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Email='$email' and Pass ='$pass' " ;
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
$rows1 = mysql_num_rows($res1);

if($rows == 1)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL'] = $row['Email'];
$_SESSION['SESS_NAME'] = $row['Name'];
$_SESSION['SESS_PASS'] = $row['Pass'];
$_SESSION['SESS_TYPE'] = 'A';
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED'] = 1;
header("Location: somewhere.php");
die();

}
else if($rows1 == 1)
{
$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1);
$_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL1'] = $row['Email'];
$_SESSION['SESS_NAME1'] = $row['Name'];
$_SESSION['SESS_PASS1'] = $row['Pass'];
$_SESSION['SESS_TYPE1'] = 'B';
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGED'] = 1;
header("Location: somewhere.php");
die();
}
else {
echo '<script language = "javascript">';
echo 'alert("Fail login")';
echo '</script>';
echo "<script>window.location.assign('somewhere.php')</script>";
die();
}
?>
```

Your If-Statement is also no correct. As mentioned in other answers it should be like this:
**somewhere.php** *Edit*

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
include("configuration.php");
?>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_EXIST'])){
        if ($_SESSION['SESS_EXIST'] == true && $_SESSION['SESS_TYPE'] == 'A' ){
            ?> //this is the user html information form <?php
        } 
        else if ($_SESSION['SESS_EXIST'] == true && $_SESSION['SESS_TYPE1'] == 'B' ){
            ?> //this is the admin html information form <?php
        }
    } else { ?> //ask user/admin to login html form
        <form action ="login.php">
            <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i got an error undefined index on  else if ($_SESSION['SESS_EXIST'] == true && $_SESSION['SESS_TYPE1'] == 'B' ) even though the first on was correct

Comment: I added an outer If-Statement with isset().

Comment: You don't need the `$_SESSION['SESS_EXIST'] == true`s with the outer check. Notices will be thrown for `$_SESSION['SESS_TYPE']` as well though.

Comment: still the same thing error undefined index on if ($_SESSION['SESS_EXIST'] == true && $_SESSION['SESS_TYPE'] == 'A' ) and  else if ($_SESSION['SESS_EXIST'] == true && $_SESSION['SESS_TYPE1'] == 'B' ){

Comment: It's a notice, not an error. And this type of notice don't affect your script.

Comment: yup it's a notice, but the form is not displaying.

Comment: Do you have a script that Loggs you out? Please call session_destroy(); one time and try it again

Answer (score 1):

Hi your condition never gets true

```
if (isset($_SESSION['SESS_TYPE']) && $_SESSION['SESS_TYPE'] == 'A') {
   // your   code here
}


  `isset` — Determine if a `variable` is set and is not `NULL`. `Returns` `TRUE` if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.
```